# Cassandra Reaper sidecar configuration needed/useful in Kubernetes Pod?

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes

I am preparing to run Cassandra Reaper 3.5.0 against Cassandra 4.1.x as a sidecar in a Kubernetes Pod (in a single Cassandra cluster).

The documentation for Reaper seems to imply that it is self-configuring when run as a sidecar in a Pod, apart, perhaps, from creating/distributing its keyspace. Is there any advantage or requirement for configuring it explicitly?